# Proving that $\vec{r'}(t)$ is orthogonal to $\vec{r''}(t)$

Tags: calculus, vectors

With a given nonzero vector $\vec{r}(t)$, how do I that $\vec{r'}(t)$ is orthogonal to $\vec{r''}(t)$? The length ($||\vec{r'}(t)||$ is constant.)
This is what I have tried so far.

Let $\vec{r}(t)= <f(t),g(t),h(t)>$. Then, $\vec{r'}(t)$ is $<f'(t),g'(t),h'(t)>$. And $\vec{r''}(t)$ is $<f''(t),g''(t),h''(t)>$.

For vectors to be orthogonal to each other, their dot products must be 0, meaning $\vec{r'}(t)\cdot\vec{r''}(t)=0$. This is where I get stuck. How do I prove that $\vec{r'}(t)\cdot\vec{r''}(t)=f'(t)\cdot f''(t)+g'(t)\cdot g''(t)+h'(t)\cdot h''(t) =0$?

Comment: Isn't $\left\Vert r'(t) \right\Vert$ constant?

Comment: Let $r(t)=(1,t,,t^2)$, then $r'(t)=(0,1,2t)$ and $r^{''}(t)=(0,0,2)$ and they are not orthogonal.

Comment: Oh yeah. $||r'(t)||$ is constant in the question. @mwt I do not understand that part though. Can you explain why it has to be constant?

Comment: When it's constant we have $r'(t) \cdot r'(t) = C$ for some $C\in\mathbb{R}$. Now try to differentiate both sides of this equation.

Comment: @mwt Oh! That is a very smart way to approach the proof. We differentiate both sides by applying the chain rule for the left. The constant becomes 0 and we get that the dot product of the one prime and the two prime is 0.

Comment: @JadenLee You're right!

Comment: @JadenLee But to use that you need to either know or prove that the derivative works on the dot product the same way as the product rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align*}
f'(t)\cdot f''(t)+g'(t)\cdot g''(t)+h'(t)\cdot h''(t)&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}(f'^2+g'^2+h'^2)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\|r'(t)\|^2 \\
&=0. &&(\because \|r'(t)\|=c) 
\end{align*}

Comment: I think your $\because$ should be on the bottom line.

Comment: @J.G. yes you are right. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

These problems are usually solved ``backwards'' by taking the derivative of given information. For example since $\|\vec{r'}\|=c$ you have
$\vec{r'}\cdot \vec{r'}=c^2$ and then taking derivatives on both sides you obtain
$2\vec{r'}\cdot \vec{r''}=0$ which implies that the two are orthogonal.

Answer (score 2):

Since

$\vec r'(t) \cdot \vec r'(t) = \Vert \vec r'(t) \Vert^2 = \text{constant}, \tag 1$

$(\vec r'(t) \cdot \vec r'(t))' = 0; \tag 2$

but

$(\vec r'(t) \cdot \vec r'(t))' = \vec r''(t) \cdot \vec r'(t) + \vec r'(t) \cdot \vec r''(t) = 2\vec r'(t) \cdot r''(t), \tag 3$

whence *via* (2),

$\vec r'(t) \cdot r''(t) = 0,  \tag 4$

that is, $\vec r'(t)$ and $\vec r''(t)$ are orthogonal.